# How to connect login button with mysql database

Tags: vb.net

my code is a login form, it cant run because of some errors in code. i dont know how to debug it.
i am a beginner in programming

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cmdsignin.Click
    If Txtusername.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input the Username", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Txtpassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input the   password", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Try
        Dim DataRead As OdbcReader
        Dim CmDSave As New OdbcCommand
        With CmDSave
            .Connection = dbconnection
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '" & Txtusername.Text & "' and password= '" & Txtpassword.Text & "', conn"

            .Parameters.Add("p1", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtusername.Text
            .Parameters.Add("p1", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtpassword.Text
            DataRead = .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    If DataRead.HasRows() Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login success!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        MDIMenu.Show()
        Me.Close()

    Else

        MsgBox("Invalid Login information.!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If

    dbconnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: If there are errors then you should share what those errors are. If you can narrow down your issues and ask questions specifically targeted at those issues, you are more likely to get assistance.

Comment: " it cant run because of some errors in code." That's great news, because learning to debug code is one of the first and most valuable lessons to learn.

Comment: Giving both parameters the same name "p1" isn't good.

Comment: There are debugging tutorials on the web. Use them. It's not for us to teach you how to debug or to do it for you.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i'm using mysql yog server database

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering what database you are using that requires ODBC. I have separated the User Interface code from the database code. I am not sure what an `OdbcReader` is. Do you have a custom class with this name?

Database objects like commands and connections need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` will handle this even if there is an error. These objects should be declared in the method where they are used so the Using blocks can be used.

You can pass the connection string to the Connection constructor and pass the `CommandText` and `Connection` to the constructor of the command.

A Select query is not a NonQuery. `ExecuteNonQuery` is used with Insert, Update and Delete commands.

Your parameters are useless because they don't appear in `CommandText`.

```
Private ConnStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Txtusername.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input the Username", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Txtpassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input the   password", "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Success As Boolean
    Try
        Success = IsLoginValid(Txtusername.Text, Txtpassword.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    If Success Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login success!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        MDIMenu.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login information.!", "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsLoginValid(UName As String, PWord As String) As Boolean
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using dbconnection As New OdbcConnection(ConnStr),
            CmDSave As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= p1 and password= p2;", dbconnection)
        CmDSave.Parameters.Add("p1", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = UName
        CmDSave.Parameters.Add("p2", Odbc.OdbcType.VarChar, 45).Value = PWord
        dbconnection.Open()
        Using reader = CmDSave.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

This could be done easier but without knowing what flavor of sql you need I left the select alone.